# Potential of a single Dipole vs. Polarization Formulation

Tags: electromagnetism

I have a few quick questions on dipole fields and their connection to the polarization of dielectrics.

To set the scene, here's what I know so far... To a first approximation, the potential field of an electrically-neutral charge distribution is
$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}$$

where p is the dipole moment of the distribution. The derivation starts with the approximation that
$$\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}\approx\frac{1}{r}-\mathbf{r'}\cdot\nabla \frac{1}{r}$$
and continues as follows
$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int{\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|}} dV'\approx \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int \rho(\mathbf{r'})\left(\frac{1}{r}-\mathbf{r'}\cdot\nabla\frac{1}{r}\right)dV'=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}$$

where integration takes place over all space. My first question is this: as far as I can tell, the approximation above is a Taylor series for 1/r' about the point r. However, it is noted that the approximation above is valid only when
$$r\gt\gt r'$$
How can this be reconciled with the fact that a Taylor series is generally most accurate for points very close to the point of expansion? It seems that we're dealing with the opposite case here.

My second question has to do with how to reconcile the above with Griffiths' expressions for the field of a polarized object. He plainly claims that

$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{(r-r')}}{|\mathbf{r-r'}|^3}$$

(without acknowledging that it is different from the above equation), and says that

$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int{\frac{\mathbf{P(r')}\cdot\mathbf{(r-r')}}{\mathbf{|r-r'|^3}}}dV'$$

where P is the volumetric polarization field of the medium. My confusion is that:

1. A dipole moment is a vector, and vectors don't have a location. Yet, we are now assigning locations (r') to our dipole elements.
2. The dipole approximation is only valid for points far away from the distribution, and the dipole moment of two non-overlapping neutral charge distributions is simply the sum of the two moments. Why is this formulation needed? Can the charge distribution not be handled just as easily with a single dipole moment? After all, we're really far away from the distribution!
3. I can informally connect equations 1 and 5 as follows: Equation 1 is spherically symmetric about the origin, so we can pretend that the dipole moment vector lives at the origin. In order for the field to transform correctly under translations, it has to take on the form in Equation 5. Nonetheless, is there a more rigorous derivation for this? I've tried expanding 1/r about different points with various substitutions, but I haven't had any success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Zangwill's Modern Electrodynamics contains the following argument which is credited to Maxwell.

Consider a charge $-q/s$ at $\mathbf{r_0}$ and a charge $+q/s$ at $\mathbf{r_0+s\hat{d}}$. The configuration's dipole moment is
$$\mathbf{p}=-\frac{q}{s}\mathbf{r_0}+\frac{q}{s}\left(\mathbf{r_0}+s\mathbf{\hat{d}}\right)=q\mathbf{\hat{d}}$$

The potential  field is
$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q/s}{|\mathbf{r-r_0-s\hat{d}}|}-\frac{q/s}{|\mathbf{r-r_0}|}\right)$$
From the law of cosines,
$$|\mathbf{r-r_0-}s\mathbf{\hat{d}}|=\sqrt{\mathbf{|r-r_0|^2}+s^2-2sr\mathbf{|r-r_0|} \cos{\phi} }$$

where $\phi$ is the angle between $\mathbf{r-r_0}$ and $\mathbf{\hat{d}}$. Plugging this into the equation for $V(\mathbf{r})$ and taking the limit as $s$ approaches 0 yields

$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\cos{\phi}}{|\mathbf{r-r_0}|^2}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\mathbf{p}\cdot(\mathbf{r-r_0)}}{|\mathbf{r-r_0}|^3}$$

The continuous analog, in which an integral is taken over all space, is the equation above.

I still think that the treatment of polarization is a bit weird, since we are assuming that $r>>r'$, and at that point, the exact location of the electric dipole shouldn't be particularly meaningful. Nonetheless, that's how it's treated.

If somebody else has any meaningful insights, I would appreciate it.